# why does my submit button not do anything?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created two html pages; main info, and Entrance page. the Entrance page is supposed to act similar to a password so that under aged users do not enter the page. problem is my submit button is not doing anything. I would highly appreciate if somebody could help me get it to work since I need to finish it today.
Here is the code I have so far:

```
<html>

<head>
<!-- this is how you add a code comment-->
 <title> Entrance Page </title>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#CEF6F5">

<form>

<h2 align=center><u> Please fill out the following information to proceed to the festival: </u></h2>

<br><br>First Name:<input type="text" name="First Name" id="first">    Last Name:<input type="text" 
name="Last Name" id="last">

<br><br> age:<select name="age" id="age">
<option value="1"> below 10 </option>
<option value="2"> 10 </option>
<option value="3"> 11 </option>
<option value="4"> 12 </option>
<option value="5"> 13 </option>
<option value="6"> 14 </option>
<option value="7"> 15 </option>
<option value="8"> 16 </option>
<option value="9"> 17 </option>
<option value="10"> 18 </option>
<option value="11"> 19 </option>
<option value="12"> 20 </option>
<option value="13"> above 20 </option>

</select>


</form>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<p align="center"> <button type="submit" onclick="run()"> Submit </button> </p>

<a href="Cost%20of%20an%20Event.html" id="pass"> </a>
<a href="Cost%20of%20an%20Event%20Entrance%20page.html" id="block"> </a>

<p><p id="p1">  </p>

<script>
    
    var firstName = document.getElementById("first").value 
    var lastName = document.getElementById("last").value
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value
    var isNum = " ";
    
    isNum = isNum + isNaN(firstName)
    
    function run() {
        var firstName = document.getElementById("first").value 
        var lastName = document.getElementById("last").value
        if (age < 10 ) {
        window.alert("your too young to enter in this event!")//go back to Entrance page
    } else if (age > 10) {
        window.alert("welcome to the Oktoberfest website!");
        window.location.replace("Cost%20of%20an%20Event.html");//go to main website
    } else if (age == 10) {
        window.alert("lucky! you are just barely old enough to join!")
        window.location.replace("Cost%20of%20an%20Event.html");//go to main website
    }
}

    
    if (isNum == true) {
        window.alert("your name cannot be a number");    
    }//go back to Entrance page

    
    while (firstName.length ==0) {
        window.alert ("you didn't enter a first name ")
        document.getElementById("block").value//go back to Entrance page
        
    while (lastNamet.length ==0) {
        window.alert ("you didn't enter a last name ")
        document.getElementById("block").value//go back to Entrance page
        

</script>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Please use indents in your code otherwise it will become unreadable.

Answer (score 3):

Because your `submit` button is outside of your `form` element. This is allowed, but you'd need to add `form="id of form here"` to associate it with the `form`.

Even if you fix this issue, all that will happen is that your page will refresh because you also need to specify an `action` and a `method` for your `form` so that it knows how and where to submit the form data.

Learn about the `form` element [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).

You've also got several other problems:

- You don't have closing brackets at the end of each of your `while`
  blocks. Your `while` loops run immediately (before the user has had a
  chance to input anything into the form) and so they immediately cause
  `alert()` messages and get you into an infinite loop. You should
  probably stay away from `while` and just check the input in the
  `submit` event of the `form` and if the input isn't right, display
  your error - - no need for a loop.

And your use of HTML is incorrect in several places:

- The `bgcolor` and `align` attributes are deprecated. All formatting
  should be done with CSS, not HTML.
- The heading elements (`h1`, `h2`, etc.) are for defining sections of
  the document. They should not be used because of the formatting
  applied to the text within them. As such, you shouldn't have an `h2`
  if you aren't creating a sub-section of an `h1`, which you are not.
- The `<br>` element should not be used to create artificial vertical
  white space. Again, CSS is for layout and styling. `br` is meant to
  force a line break between content, not for introducing blank lines.

Comment: for some reason it keeps on saying the alert "your too young to enter this event" no matter what "age" I enter.

Comment: @BennetSchmidt There's a lot more you'll need to do to make this work properly. That issue could be related to the fact that the value selected in the drop down is treated like a string, even though it's a numeric character (all data in HTML is strings). You can prepend a `+` to a string that can be converted to a number like: `var age = +document.getElementById("age").value;`.

Comment: @BennetSchmidt Add `consolel.log(age)` just before the `if` statement begins so that you can see what that value is.

Comment: it is still not working. I think the problem is related to my if statement.

Comment: @BennetSchmidt As I said, you have other issues with your code. You should make the adjustments I've pointed out and post a new question related to your current problem. Also, did you do what I suggested 2 comments up?

Comment: I got the alerts to work!(the if statement)

Comment: but it is not linking to my other webpage for some reason

Comment: @BennetSchmidt Please read my answer and my comments. You need to configure the `form` tag to know where and how to go when the submit button is clicked and you need to move the submit button into the form. If it still doesn't work, please post a new question with your updated code. We don't take one question and solve it and then then another and another that are unrelated in one post.

Comment: could someone please help?

Comment: @BennetSchmidt PLEASE follow my guidance and post a new question with your updated code.